# Nucleoside triphosphates vs nucleotide diphosphates

Tags: biochemistry, nomenclature, nucleic-acids

A nucleoside can be defined as a nucleotide without its phosphate group. Thus, a nucleoside triphosphate (NTP) is a nucleoside bound to 3 phosphates.

This in turn must be equivalent to a nucleotide (whose name implies the inclusion of one phosphate already) plus an additional 2 phosphates. Thus, would it be appropriate to refer to an NTP as a **nucleotide diphosphate**?

Comment: I don't think this is technically incorrect, but why on earth would you want to give it a deliberate confusing name?

Comment: Did you check on Wikipedia or in Biochemistry at NCBI bookshelf before posting? Posters to this list are expected to make a reasonable attempt to find an answer from a standard source.  Or are you trying to make some sort of clever point? If so, it is not "appropriate" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nucleoside is nucleotide without a phosphate group. That is something we say to understand and correlate nucleotide and nucleoside. But if followed Terminology by IUPAC a nucleotide should contain only one phosphate group, not more than that. Though NTP is a type of nucleotide, however, for the sake of technical terminology, nucleotides are given classifications as nucleosides with a suffix describing the number of phosphates present in a specific unit. For example, if a nucleotide has one phosphate, it is a nucleoside monophosphate (NMP). If the nucleotide has two phosphates, then it is called a nucleoside diphosphate (NDP), and for three, it is a nucleoside triphosphate (NTP). So you can say NTP as  nucleotide diphosphate, but considering the fact that nomenclature also indicate the chemical property of the compound, it would not be right.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotide)